# How does a Java Event, specifically the javax.enterprise.event.fire() behave?

Tags: java, ejb, cdi

I have the following situation (running on JBoss AS6 and AS7):

- An Singleton EJB with a scheduled method.
- An injected Event of type `SomethingChangedEvent`

Consider the following examples:

```
@Singleton
public final class Scheduler {
    @Inject
    private Event<SomethingChangedEvent> event;

    @Schedule
    private void scheduleSomething() {
        event.fire(new SomethingChangedEvent());
    }
}
```

I would expect this event to be added to some kind of queue on the server and distributed by it. Any methods that observe this kind of event by using `@Observers` will be notified. The `event.fire()` method will return immediately.

However, I face the following problem: Sometimes, the `event.fire()` method takes like two or three minutes to return, causing havoc in my schedule since it is assumed to be invoked once every ten seconds.

So the questions are: How is this possible? What happens to events that are fired, but no one observes them? Is there a queue that can overflow?

Regards,
Sven

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CDI event processing occurs synchronously. There is actually a [proposal](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-31?_sscc=t) to include an asynchronous processing model into the spec, but it is still being voted on. In the meantime there are two ways 'forcing' asynchronous processing:

1. Use JMS - yes this is a kludge because it is reverting back to older Java EE technologies. But it works
2. Use an [@Asynchronous](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html) method on both producer and observer methods, to split those method invocations into separate, container managed threads.

Applying second method to your code example:

```
@Singleton
public final class Scheduler {
    @Inject
    private Event<SomethingChangedEvent> event;

    @Asynchronous
    private void scheduleSomething() {
        event.fire(new SomethingChangedEvent());
    }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. That solved my problem (hopefully :) ). In fact, the method that observed the event got stuck.

Comment: I was using the 2. method, and there was no need to mark the producer Asyncronous.